# Chromecast YouTube from Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, chromecast

How can I cast YouTube videos from Internet Explorer? I've written an IE plugin that successfully injects the `js` files right after `<head>`, but I have not had any success making the Google Cast icon appear in the player. What needs to change? Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: @user3173819 I'm not having issues adding the `js` files into the page. The problem is that the cast icon isn't appearing when I insert `api_script.js`. (Copied from the Google Cast extension)

Comment: Pres F12 key and go to tab console to see the debug theres you can foud the exaclity erro that  is happens :)

Comment: @user3173819 No errors show in the console once I remove all references to the `chrome.*` other than `chrome.cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Chromecast is not supported on IE or any other browser except Chrome. In Chrome, you need the Cast Extension.